# In Pages, What is this Line Under a Rectangle Shape?

Tags: pages, iwork

There is a persistent thing going on in Pages where there is a line under a rectangle shape when I make it. How do I get rid of it? I don't want it to show up when I export the document to a PDF.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Simple.  Make sure you've selected the object you want to remove the line from.  Click your inspector, and navigate over to the *graphic tab* (see screenshot).  select *none.*  Last screenshot shows the result.

[image]

[image]