# Can I suppress the dot under an image caption in pages for macOS?

Tags: macos, pages

When I use the media box to add a photo, I seem to be required to add a caption. Then under the caption, there is a gray dot. These dots show up in the image files I [paste into Pages similar to this underline situation, but not the same](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/in-pages-what-is-this-line-under-a-rectangle-shape).

[image: screenshot of pages for macOS showing a grey dot under an image]

How can I ditch the dot?

Comment: Could you tell us the macOS version and Pages version just to make it easier.

Comment: You might also tell us the steps you are taking to add the image and if you are using a particular Pages template. I couldn't replicate your problem.

Comment: I put a placeholder in the page, then added a photo. There is a grey dot under the caption box. No template, pages 8.2.1 Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs when you choose the "Image Gallery" option from one of two places either:

- Menu Bar > Insert > Image Gallery
- Tool Bar > Media > Image Gallery

The dot underneath is used to support multiple images being in that box similar to an image gallery function on a website.

The reason that you do not see this when you copy and paste an image or drag one in is that it inserts the image as an image and not as a single image within an image gallery.

The solution is to delete the image gallery and insert the image into the Document by one of the following ways:

- Drag and Drop from Finder onto the Pages Document
- Copy and Paste the image
- Menu Bar > Insert > Chose ... (Select file)
- Tool Bar > Media > Chose ... (Select file)

*I have added an image to further illustrate this incase it was not clear.*
[image: An illustration of the differences between an "Image Gallery" and an inserted image in Pages and some of the indicators to show you if you have encountered this situation.]

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove the dot below a picture inserted via the Image Gallery. The Image Gallery is a special feature of Pages that allows many photographs or pictures to occupy the same space in a document and to be viewed only one a time. It is usually not the preferred way to place a single picture (or multiple pictures that are to be displayed separately) into a Pages document. See [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eBu9rj2UnQ) if you wish to learn more about how to better use Image Gallery.

However, you can avoid the dot under a picture inserted into a Pages document by adding it to the document without using the Image Gallery feature.

Click on the **Media** option on the **Pages toolbar** at the top and click on **Choose** instead of Image Gallery. Then locate the image or photo and select it in the window that will appear and click on **Insert**. The photo or image will be added to your Pages document without the caption and the dot. Once added, you can move or resize the photo or image as you like.

You can add a caption yourself below (or above) the picture by adding and writing in a text box below or above the picture. You can add a text box by clicking on the **Text** option on the **Pages Toolbar**. To make sure the picture and the caption always appear together, first click on one of them and then press and hold the Command or the Shift button while clicking on the second one. Once both are selected, **right click** and choose **Group**.

You can also directly paste the photo or image to your Pages document without a caption and the accompanying dot by selecting and copying the file directly from inside a **Finder app** window after locating it in the Finder. You can again create a caption for the picture using the Text option.